# Cassandra - NoSQL Data modeling

Tags: cassandra, nosql

As I am modeling in NoSQL with Cassandra for the first time, I have a question.
My use case is for a school, where I have a operational table called TRIP with the next columns:

> VehicleID DriverID ScheduleID TripDate StudentID Student_Checkintime student_CheckoutTime Student_CheckinLocation

`VehicleID DriverID ScheduleID TripDate` columns are static for a day.
`Student_Checkintime student_CheckoutTime Student_CheckinLocation` and students columns like are dynamic instead.

My question: Can anyone suggest how to design this in Cassandra? I know CREATE TYPE in Cassandra, but are there any alternates?

Comment: To answer it's important to know how you need to query these data

Comment: More on rationale of above comment. Instead of thinking 3rd normal form and how to model your tables to represent what your data, you want to denormalize and model your tables on your queries.

Comment: thanks, I do agree. But my problem is, analytics is in next stage. Max what can i  input you is, the use case is to ensure students safety. Admin team in the school,  will watch students safety pick ups/drops every moment. They have many vehicles,many drivers,many schedules with certain set of associations of these. They can track routes/vehicles using GPS every 3 mins.